# Dynamic tag based on props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to receive props which are a union type of either the props of a `<button>` or the props of an `<a>`. Then, I want to render the relevant component.

I tried the following ([TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4SwWwBwewJwC7AEoFMCGBjJAzOMJgByODbIgWAChrRgEBPKVYAWQYCEBXBBGAOwAK%20KAGdgAXmAAKWnVAAfFGQQA6brwEAJACqsAMgEFecMACMeqUQB5dBjX34BRADaoIqfggB8c%20cCU0LDVDfkwAC3g7IxNzSxto0Ij4V3dPHz9gAEpqTNQAD1hEYEwBUSR2BwFJGSgRUQAuNk4eR2EYMSzJbxlMuiJw0hwicH5gOo7RPv9gAH5ga3RgAG9VNYmxAF9gAHpfKhn5JusLTTHV9frtvcycqiA)):

```
import React from 'react'

type MyButtonProps = (
    | ({ tag: "button" } & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>)
    | ({ tag: "a" } & React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>)
)

export const MyButton = ({ tag, ...props }: MyButtonProps) => (
    tag === "a"
        ? <a {...props} />
        : <button {...props} />
)
```

This produces the following error:

```
Type '{ autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; form?: string | undefined; formAction?: string | undefined; formEncType?: string | undefined; formMethod?: string | undefined; ... 258 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Type '{ download?: any; href?: string | undefined; hrefLang?: string | undefined; media?: string | undefined; ping?: string | undefined; rel?: string | undefined; target?: HTMLAttributeAnchorTarget | undefined; ... 255 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Type '{ download?: any; href?: string | undefined; hrefLang?: string | undefined; media?: string | undefined; ping?: string | undefined; rel?: string | undefined; target?: HTMLAttributeAnchorTarget | undefined; ... 255 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined'.(2322)
```

The desired usage of the `MyButton` component is as follows:

```
const App = () => (
  <>
    <MyButton tag="button" onClick={doSomething}>I'm a button</MyButton>
    <MyButton tag="a" href="http://example.com" target="_blank">I'm a link</MyButton>
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I test the value of the `href` prop to know whether I should render an `<a>` element instead of a `<button>` element, I ended up changing the type of the `href` prop to make it required, like so:

```
import React from 'react'

type MyButtonProps = (
    | React.ComponentProps<"button">
    | React.ComponentProps<"a"> & { href: string }
)

export const MyButton = (props: MyButtonProps) => (
    'href' in props
        ? <a {...props} />
        : <button {...props} />
)
```

The original type of the `href` prop is `string | undefined`, which doesn't work for me because if I render an `<a>` then I know for sure that I got a value for `href`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to force the issue, since you know the props MyButton is receiving, why not split it into two components?

```
import React from 'react'

type MyButtonProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
type MyAnchorProps = React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>

export const MyButton = (props: MyButtonProps) => <button {...props} />
export const MyAnchor = (props: MyAnchorProps) => <a {...props} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have type inference on the `button` element, you can cast it:

```
import React from 'react'

type MyButtonProps = (
    | React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
    | React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
)

export const MyButton = (props: MyButtonProps) => {
    if ('href' in props) {
        return <a {...props} />
    }
    return <button {...(props as React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>)} />;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4SwWwBwewJwC7AEoFMCGBjJAzOMJgByODbIgWAChrRgEBPKVYAWQYCEBXBBGAOwAK%20KAGdgAXmAAKWnVAAfFGQQA6brwEAJACqsAMgEFecMACMeqUQB5dBjX34BRADaoIqfggB8c%20cCU0LDVDfkwAC3g7IxNzSxto0Ij4V3dPHz9gAEpqTNQAD1hEYEwBUSR2BwFJGSgRUQAuNk4eR2EYMSzJb2AAb0y6MBxpInDSHCJwfmA6jtEu-qp-f1IELjhp63Q%201V3ZsQBfYAB6XyXlg4HQVfXp4GsLTWne3dVpffF0cSDsdVbtPQxBCmR5WWyAqrONweLzeLJHU4AbkylxoVCAA)

## EDIT

Also, there is a chance you override (or the element props overridden) the `type` key of the element itself, you should give it an unique naming and ordering to make a clearer interfering:

```
import React from 'react'

type MyButtonProps = (
    | React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & { componentType: "a" }
    | React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & { componentType: "b" }
)

export const MyButton = (props: MyButtonProps) => {
    if (props.componentType === "b") {
        const { componentType, ...rest } = props;
        return <a {...rest} />
    }
    const { componentType, ...rest } = props;
    return <button {...(rest)} />;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgFlqAhAVxhggDsAFHMAM5wAvHAAUFOFLgAfRMRgA6Nh24AJACoMAMgEEOUYACN2SAQB5NOlZy4BRADZIQSLjAB8cAGRwA3nDRcSC5XGA1aJAAuOAAiFBi4AF9JaTlkdCVdLjQAC2grPQNjUwsCrNzoR2dQzx9-QPBuUPC6aJijBOTyAEoKCiQAD0hYAO4BeCYbbhFxMH4BaMn2Wz4IQW6RT18UqWBMWfnFBuDmiJFhUXaYje3yaXvRrnG-UcaQtxakABo4RT%20iZ6JGZzNYCADcOweRBgrCgXDg5hQfj%20igBMCBAHp3JCuvdAk94PUgk0PhEfii0UlgfMIXdpNDYfDzCZVPDfCixGjupj3LSuhQgA)

Comment: At first I didn't understand why I don't have type inference, but then I noticed that the type of `href` is `string | undefined`, which means that the type inference could only work for the first branch of the conditional, i.e. in case `'href' in props` is `true`. Please look at the edit I've made and see if you can tell why the inference doesn't work in that way.

Comment: Im not sure to which editing you referring to, either way "why inference doesn't work in this case" is related to a new question which you should ask, better focus on the original question.

Comment: The code in your answer is based on my original question, which I have edited a few minutes after posting it. Could you please look at the current code in my question and see if you can come up with something?

Comment: I added more explanation, hope it helps good luck